# maven site-deploy to tomcat with webdav

Tags: tomcat, maven, webdav, maven-site-plugin

I have used maven to generate a site for my project and want to use the site-deploy plugin to pubish the site to a webserver. I am using Tomcat with webdav enabled so created an empty war project and enabled webdav as described here

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/WebDav

Then i defined a distribution management in my pom.xml as described here

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/site-generation-sect-deploy-site.html

But whenever i run the site-deploy goal it fails with this

```
https://localhost:2020/project-site - Session: Opened  
 Transfer error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Uploading: ./apidocs/allclasses-frame.html to https://localhost:2020/project-site

# Transfer error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
https://localhost:2020/project-site - Session: Disconnecting  
https://localhost:2020/project-site - Session: Disconnected
```

What else do i have to do to get this working?

Comment: As it's an HTTPS URL you need to provide credentials for SSL. Did you provide them?

Comment: oops, thanks for that, I removed the 's' and i now get ######http://localhost:2020/project-site/./apidocs/allclasses-frame.html - Status code: 409
 Transfer error: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:2020/project-site/./apidocs/allclasses-frame.html. Return code is: 409